# The tab for a personal app that loads an external website in MS Teams is not loading correctly

Tags: microsoft-teams

I added a personal app that loads an external website in the form of a tab to MS Teams, but the website is not opening correctly. Are there any guides or resources available to reference?

I made changes to the configuration settings in the Azure Portal and Teams app developer portal, but the external website added to the tab is not opening correctly.

```
 "validDomains": [
"mcloudbridge.com",
"microsoft.sharepoint.com",
"fullwebsite.website.com",
"mcbapproval-t2.powerappsportals.com",
"*.powerappsportals.com",
"*.login.microsoftonline.com",
"microsoft.sharepoint-df.com",
"spoppe-a.akamaihd.net",
"spoprod-a.akamaihd.net",
"resourceseng.blob.core.windows.net",
"msft.spoppe.com",
"*.mcloudbridge.com",
"mcbstudio.onmicrosoft.com"
```

]

Comment: Have you added domain of the external website in validdomains section of manifest.
Could you please follow the prerequisites of tabs which is mentioned in following document: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/tabs/how-to/tab-requirements

Could you please share the error message and console error which you are getting?

Comment: Have you check the domain of the external website is added in validdomains section of manifest?

Comment: This is the configured manifest information.

Comment: "entityId": "6cb3c2c0-cc89-4895-a62b-1daf0fe3fafb",
      "name": "appr",
      "contentUrl": "https://mcbapproval-t2.powerappsportals.com/new-page",
      "websiteUrl": "https://mcbapproval-t2.powerappsportals.com",
      "scopes": [
        "personal"
      ]

Comment: Could you please share your manifest zip to test at our end?

Comment: The websiteUrl is not accessible in browser also.